# Null value while trying to read XML data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web

I tried to read XML data that matches my post id string (not null) attributes, but it returns null even though I have tried several times.

```
protected void Update_btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String new_title = newtitle.Text.ToString();
    String new_description = update_des.Value.ToString();
    String postid = Request.QueryString["pid"];

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(postid);

    string filename = "C:\\Users\\user\\Source\\Repos\\FoodBlog\\FoodBlog\\Data\\blog_post.xml";
    XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
    xml_doc.Load(filename);

    XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(filename);

    XmlNodeList elemList = xml_doc.GetElementsByTagName("post");
    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string getValue = elemList[i].Attributes[postid].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(getValue);
    }
}
```

XML data :

```
<Posts>
  <post pid="pid2623">
    <title>Test</title>
    <description>Test</description>
    <subtitle>Test</subtitle>
    <date>7/29/2018 12:00:00 AM</date>
    <author>est</author>
  </post>
</Posts>
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: What is `null`? Any exceptions?

Comment: @EdSF Hi sir, it doesn't return any value for some reason. I will upload a picture to explain the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your code

you need to modify those lines, because in the for loop you are looking for an element that contains an attribute with name **pid2623** but actually you need to look for a post whose **pid** attribute contains value **pid2623**

```
XmlNodeList elemList = xml_doc.GetElementsByTagName("post");
for (int i=0;i<elemList.Count; i ++)
{
    string getValue = elemList[i].Attributes[postid].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(getValue);
}
```

to

```
 XmlNode elemList = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/Posts/Post[@pid='"+ postid +"']");
```

Comment: Hi sir, I have implemented your code and decided to retrieve the value of title but still not getting any values , wonder why ? Sorry I am really new 


(Your code)
XmlNode elemList = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/Posts/Post[@pid=" + postid + "]");
(My code)
            String test = elemList.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);

Comment: I am sorry, could you please write the line of code that you retrieve all xml element in elemList variable.

one more thing there was a problem in my code i forgot to add single quote, if you copy my code exactly and paste it in your editor, it should works now

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use Linq To SQL IMHO:

```
XDocument xml_doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

foreach (var p in xml_doc.Elements("Posts"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug
         .WriteLine((string)p.Element("post").Attribute("pid"));
}
```

and you could query a specific post like this:

```
var post = from p in xml_doc.Elements("Posts")
           where (string)p.Element("post").Attribute("pid") == postid
           select p.Element("post");
```